# Delete array from an offset

Tags: c++, delete-operator

Lets say I allocate an array of ints

```
int test[] = new int[100];
```

I take a pointer to somewhere in the middle

```
int *temp = &test[50];
```

Then I call delete[] on the temp

```
delete[] temp
```

How will the compiler know the size of elements to delete in this case?

Comment: Can you explain the circumstances in which you'd want to do this?

Comment: If you're attempting to shrink the array, it can't be done like that. Use `std::vector` if you need resizing.

Comment: I was wondering if I had a large array and needed to free some space quickly - would it be possible to just free unnecessary things rather than making a copy and free the original...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It won't (or will, I don't know). You're invoking **undefined behavior**. You're only allowed to call `delete[]` on a pointer allocated with `new[]`.

For example, I get a crash in MSVS.

Answer (score 3):

You *have to* pass the same memory location which was returned by `new[]`, passing anything else is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that. A compiler has to keep track of the size of memory that it allocates. The standard does not say how it must to this. Some compilers store the size of the allocated memory just before the returned address. In such cases what you're doing can lead to undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no.
Because delete operator need to locate the location of the memory block and it's size, which is mostly ahead the first member of the allocated array.
you should have a look at the "Inside c++ object model"

Comment: "How will the compiler know the size of elements to delete in this case?" - "The answer is no"  :)

Comment: Thanks for the Inside C++ mention :)